# Camping safety in the Everglades in May

Tags: camping, everglades

Is it safe to camp with a small tent in the Everglades park? Is there a difference regarding the different campsites?

Answer (score 5):

There are two campgrounds with different features and policies

Flamingo http://www.nps.gov/ever/planyourvisit/flamcamp.htm

Long Pine Key http://www.nps.gov/ever/planyourvisit/longpinecamp.htm

You can also opt for backcountry camping http://www.nps.gov/ever/planyourvisit/backcamp.htm

If you meant safe then yes, it is quite safe once you take the usual common sense precautions

Comment: As @mollmerx was saying the mosquitos could be awful but it varies a lot with the season. January = no mosquitos at all.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's completely safe.

However, I camped at Flamingo a few weeks ago and the mosquitoes were horrendous. They were manifold and super aggressive, which had a serious impact on our enjoyment of the trip. I'm sure it varies a lot with the weather, but bear that in mind.